# How to say to be improved?

Tags: word-choice, verb

So if I wanted to say *to be improved*, should I use *verbessert werden* or *sich verbessern*?

z.B.

> Es kann verbessert werden.

Oder...

> Es kann sich verbessern.

Comment: Depends. What is the full English sentence?

Answer (score 6):

> "Es kann sich verbessern"

implies that "it" can improve itself.
"It" can be the weather, for instance.

> "Es kann verbessert werden"

means that someone else can improve "it".
"It" can be the weather control machine, for instance :)

Answer (score 3):

*to be improved* is **passive** (vs. "to improve") and probably should be translated with passive.

> Es kann verbessert werden

Answer (score 0):

There is a single German word addressing all genders and things:

> Verbesserungswürdig

Comment: It doesn't really mean that it *can* be improved though...

Comment: "Wir arbeiten kontinuierlich an der Steigerung unseres Optimierungspotentials"

Comment: Foobar has to be improved before shipping.

Comment: Quite mysterious comments here: does anybody care to elaborate (possibly stating reason for downvote)? I guess userunknown wants to point out, that there are contexts, where my proposal does not work, which is hardly a surprise.

Comment: 'It could still be improved, but it is a very good effort.'